# Java compiling error when passing values between classes

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass a JTEXTFIELD value I created in class 2 to class 3. My terminal when compiling shows me this:

```
error: incompatible types
        username = class2.username;
```

My code structure is this.

```
    class 1
    - has main
    -class2 c2 = new class2

    class 2 (extends JFrame)
    - JTextField username = new JTextField("", 15);
    -method gui here
    -method actionlistener here
       if e.getsource == submit
          class3 c3 = new class3
          c3.connection();

class 3
-method connection
-string username declared here
- username = class2.username
```

How can i get the value from class 2 into class 3?

Comment: For help with code, quote ***code***.

Comment: right so what do I do? get the value of the textfield then pass to string?

Comment: cheers for that. Wasn't aware you could use another . in a statement. Isit possible to give comments "best answer" ?

Comment: I'll write my comment as an answer and you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were getting the error because you are assigning `JTextField` to a `String` which would result in `incompatible types` error.

To be able to get the value of `JTextField` you have to use the `getText()` method like so:

```
username = class2.username.getText();
```

`getText()` returns a `String` which you can then assign to any `String` you like.

Here is the documentation for `getText()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()

Comment: THats actually not working. No data gets passed? Any idea why? I did a system out on class 2 and it showed my data but in class 3 nothing was displayed on system.out

Comment: @Bobski It is difficult to tell what's going on without seeing the code but I would assume your problem has to do with initialization order. Check this out: http://norvig.com/java-iaq.html#init and also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4 to understand that.